# Soap XML Request formatting error cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element

Tags: soap, xsd, wsdl, request

I'm attempting to call a 3rd party SOAP web service, but I'm having trouble formulating my SOAP Request. I've googled the error mentioned in the title, and I cannot see where I'm going wrong.

When I call the web service, it returns the error in the title for the element "VirksomhedSoeg".

My XML Request is this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soap:Header>
      <wsa:Action>urn:#VirksomhedSoeg</wsa:Action>
      <wsa:MessageID>uuid:23ff9f74-8347-5215-a967-a3134f23e5fd</wsa:MessageID>
      <wsa:ReplyTo>
         <wsa:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:Address>
      </wsa:ReplyTo>
      <wsa:To>https://test.tinglysning.dk/etl/services/ElektroniskAkt</wsa:To>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
     <VirksomhedSoeg xmlns="http://rep.oio.dk/tinglysning.dk/service/message/elektroniskakt/1/">
     </VirksomhedSoeg>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The XSD file for VirksomhedSoeg looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:eakt="http://rep.oio.dk/tinglysning.dk/schema/elektroniskakt/1/" xmlns:eamsg="http://rep.oio.dk/tinglysning.dk/service/message/elektroniskakt/1/" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://rep.oio.dk/tinglysning.dk/service/message/elektroniskakt/1/" version="22.0.0" xml:lang="DA">

  <import namespace="http://rep.oio.dk/tinglysning.dk/schema/elektroniskakt/1/" schemaLocation="http://rep.oio.dk/tinglysning.dk/schema/elektroniskakt/1/VirksomhedSoegningKriterie.xsd"/>

  <element name="VirksomhedSoeg" type="eamsg:VirksomhedSoegType">
      <annotation>
         <documentation>Benyttes til at søge efter en virksomhed i e-Akten.</documentation>
      </annotation>
  </element>

  <complexType name="VirksomhedSoegType">
      <sequence>
         <element ref="eakt:VirksomhedSoegningKriterie"/>
      </sequence>
  </complexType>
</schema>
```

I've been sitting with this for a while and I've tried a bunch of different little changes to make this message be parsed, but so far no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you sure that the VirksomhedSoeg.xsd are available for your SOAP client?

Comment: Sorry I might not have been clear enough.. I'm getting the error from the server. It's available to me just fine :)

Comment: @bech Did you ever figure out how the e-tinglysning service wants its soap requests?

Comment: I did, but it was quite the hassle. The XSD files result in lists with invalid types in all objects, which must be adjusted for it to work. After that I had to manually sign requests because that didn't work either (did that with a SoapInspector IIRC).

I wish I could share some actual code with you, but this question was asked for work purposes so It's proprietary.

Answer (score 1):

According to OP, the original problem was solved, but for posterity's sake, here's what we found:

This appears to be a problem related to the specific service (Elektronisk Tinglysning, offered by Tinglysningsretten, the Land Registration Court in Denmark), not a client error.

While the service is indeed a SOAP service, it seems like there is a separate XML validation layer being applied **before** the SOAP handling kicks in. This layer (oddly enough) does not recognize the namespace contents of the namespace http://rep.oio.dk/tinglysning.dk/schema/elektroniskakt/1/ and so has to be fed the (nominal) schemaLocation of the body's child element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soap:Header>
  <wsa:Action>urn:#VirksomhedSoeg</wsa:Action>
  <wsa:MessageID>uuid:23ff9f74-8347-5215-a967-a3134f23e5fd</wsa:MessageID>
 </soap:Header>
 <soap:Body>
  <VirksomhedSoeg xmlns="http://rep.oio.dk/tinglysning.dk/service/message/elektroniskakt/1/"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://rep.oio.dk/tinglysning.dk/service/message/elektroniskakt/1/ http://rep.oio.dk/tinglysning.dk/service/message/elektroniskakt/1/.xsd"
  >
   ...
  </VirksomhedSoeg>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Notice the two attributes *xmlns:xsi* and *xsi:schemaLocation* -- these are the key to allowing the validation to succeed. I haven't been able to find the documentation for this in the relevant documentation, so the fix was found from experimentation (or suppressed memories.)

Signing the request using WS-Security is **not** required for lookups, it's enough to use a mTLS client certificate which must be pre-registered with Tinglysningsretten (the Land Registration Court).

Comment: Well, that was a blast from the past, thanks! Incredibly, I'm still working on the same codebase, so I might have to try to switch to this at some point; seems a lot simpler than what I had to go through iirc :)

Comment: Good to know - please report on how you solved it.

Obviously, there should a better way of doing this, starting with a set of valid WSDL's and schemas (e.g. in consolidated form so more tools work out of the box -- see e.g. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=197947 ).

Having to do workarounds like this is really annoying, since you can't just use sane defaults anymore.  So much for "industry standard SOAP", eh?

And yes, sometimes old SO questions, old bugs, and even PRs get attention after a loooooong time, e.g.: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XMLBEANS-487